# Disprove: The image of a function commutes with complements

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a function, and $E \subset X$. Here is an attempt to show that $f(E^C) = (f(E))^C$:

$$y \in f(E^C) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \in E^C \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \not \in E \Rightarrow y \not \in f(E) \Rightarrow y \in (f(E))^C$$

so $f(E^C) \subset (f(E))^C$. Going the other way, we have

$$y \in (f(E))^C \Rightarrow y \not \in f(E) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \not \in E \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \in E^C \Rightarrow y \in f(E^C)$$

so $(f(E))^C \subset f(E^C)$. This is the same technique to prove that inverse images commute with complements, which is true. Why is this proof invalid for images?

Thanks.

Comment: If you need to disprove something, a counter example is sufficient. Now, imagine $E=X$ and $f(E) \ne Y$.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm also trying to understand why this proof is not valid.

Comment: $y\in f(E^C) \not\implies y\not\in f(E)$. Consider $f:\{0,1\}\to \{0\}$ and $E=\{0\}$.

Comment: Notice that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set in general. So the first implication is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first implication is wrong: $y\in f(E^{C})$ iff exists $x\in E^{C}$ such that $f(x)=y$. This does not imply that $f^{-1}(y)= \{ a\in X \mid f(a)=y \}$, which is a subset of $Y$ in general, is an element of $E^{C}$.